# Highcharts increase height of the chart displayed

Tags: highcharts

I need to increase the size of the highcharts, ie; the height parameter.

I'm using the plotAreaHeight parameter but it is not working ie; the height remains the same.

```
                chart: {
                  // type: 'bar',
        plotAreaHeight: 800,
```

Here is my fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/cucjw7xc/8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I am aware `plotAreaHeight` is not a configuration option.

Two ways to set the height of your chart:

1) use the `height` property:

```
chart: {
  height: 800
}
```

Updated Fiddle:

- https://jsfiddle.net/cucjw7xc/9/

2) Set the height on your containing div

```
#container: {
  height: 800px;
}
```

Updated Fiddle:

- https://jsfiddle.net/cucjw7xc/10/

Comment: @FernandoTorres the first fiddle is working as expected. The second fiddle doesn't appear to be applying the CSS to the #container div. Not sure the reason, but it is a 3-year old fiddle